# using output of grep command to find command

Tags: shell, find, grep

I have a problem related to searching a pattern among several files.

I want to search "Logger." pattern in jsp files,so i used the command

```
grep -ir Logger. * | find . -name *.jsp
```

Now the problem i am facing is that this command is listing all the jsp files and its not searching the pattern "Logger." in jsp files and listing them.

I just want the jsp files in which "Logger." instance is present.

Answer (score 2):

start like this 
you want to search in jsp files.

```
find . -name "*.jsp"
```

the above will output all the jsp files recursively from current directory. like below

```
1/2/ahbd.jsp
befwej/dg/wefwefw/wefwefwe/ijn.jsp
```

And now you want to find the string in just these files.

```
grep -ir Logger. (output of find)
```

so the actual complete command becomes:

```
find . -name "*.jsp"|xargs grep -ir 'Logger.'
```

magic here is done by `xargs`
it gives the output of find as an input for grep line by line.
if you remove xargs,then only the first line that is `1/2/ahbd.jsp` will be searched for the string.

there are several other ways to do this.But i feel more comfortable using this regularly

Answer (score 1):

To recursively find all `*.jsp` files containing the string `Logger.` you can do:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jsp' -exec grep -l "Logger\." {} \;
```

`grep -l` means to print only the file name if the file contains the string.
The `-exec` switch of `find` will execute the given command for each file matching the other criteria (`-type f` and `-name '*.jsp'`). The string `{}` is substituted by the filename. Some versions of `find` also support `+` instead of `{}` to feed several file names to the command (like `xargs` does) and not only one at once, e.g.:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jsp' -exec grep -l "Logger\." + \;
```

Comment: I tried this but its also listing files with ".logger" string,but i only want to list the files containing "logger." string

Comment: Yes - you are right. We have to add a backslash to the dot: `"Logger\."`. I will update the answer.

Comment: try: *find . -type f -name '*.jsp' -exec grep -l "^[\.]Logger\." + \;*

Answer (score 0):

You can just use grep for that, here's a command that should give you the results:

```
grep -ir "Logger\." * | grep ".jsp"
```

Problem is, grep will bail when you use "*.jsp" instead or "*" if you don't have at least one *.jsp* file into your root directory. So we have to tell him to look every file.

Since you give grep the `-r` (recursive) argument, it will walk the subdirectories to find the pattern "Logger.", then the second grep will only display the `.jsp` files. Note that `-i` tells grep not to care about the letter case, which is may be not what you want.

**edit**: following John's answer: we have to escape the `.` to prevent it to be taken as a regexp.

**re-edit**: actually, I think that using find is better, since it will filter the *jsp* files directly instead of grepping all the files:

```
find . -name "*.jsp" -exec grep -i "Logger\." {} \;
```

(you don't need the `-r` anymore since find takes care of recursion.

Comment: `find . -name "*.jsp" -exec grep -n "Logger\." {} \; 2>/dev/null` prevent error messages(grep: *.jsp: No such file or directory) and shows line number too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash 4+

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
for file in **/*.jsp
do
  if grep -q "Logger." "$file" ;then
    echo "found in $file"
  fi
  # or just grep -l "Logger." "$file"
done
```